# How to redirect all emails coming from a specific server to a specific account?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, sharepoint-2010

I am setting up a test SharePoint farm on a Windows 2008 R2 server to mimic our production environment. In setting this up, I would like redirect all emails that are emanating from this server (regardless of who it is addressed to) to a specific email account so that I can review them (and because we don't want to spam our users with test emails).

I have Googled on how to do this but I haven't found an answer. Is there a way to accomplish this? And if so, can you point me to the proper documentation?

Comment: Look into disabling send on the service account's mailbox in your exchange server.  Look into your Exchange server for the ability to use a filter/rule.  Or route the traffic through your spam filter and use a rule there to divert the messages.  Finally, there should be a way to configure sharepoint to disable sending to customers, perhaps do this with all sites except a small number which send to your engineers' group.  None of these are answers just where I would look.  How segregated from your production environment is the test farm?  If it's isolated, the mail messages won't go through.